# Comunicate AS3 to PHP. Send variables to a php page, but $_POST is empty

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I've created a simple quiz program, using Flash cs5.5, which sends the results of the quiz to a php page, which writes these data in a Mysql database.
So I'm trying to send simple variables from a swf file to a php page, using `$_POST`. I'm using WAMP to execute the php page.

I've created 3 files in total: 
 1. `mioQuizDB.swf` 
 2. `config.php` 
 3. `inserimentoDati.php`

So `mioQuizDB.swf` comunicates with `inserimentoDati.php`, which communicates with `config.php` (to connect to the database) and with the Mysql database.

My problems are:
 1. `inserimentoDati.php` does not opens itself when the `URLRequest` is completely loaded;
 2. In `inserimentoDati.php` the `$_POST` is empty, and I don't know why.
This is `mioQuiz.swf`:

```
var variables:URLVariables=new URLVariables();
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("inserimentoDati.php");
varSend.contentType='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';varSend.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data=variables;
// Build the varLoader variable
    var varLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
    varLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

variables.unome = nome_utente; //nome_utente is a string variable
variables.ucognome = cognome_utente; //cognome_utente is a string variable
variables.ucodice = codice_utente; //codice_utente is a string variable
variables.upunteggio = numEsatte; //numEsatte is an int variable, it's the result of the quiz
variables.sendRequest = "scriviDatiUtente";

// Send the data to the php file
varLoader.load(varSend);

    function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("scriviDatiUtente Completed!\n");
        trace(varSend.data); //I see the data in the output window of Flash
    }//end completeHandler
```

This is `inserimentoDati.php`:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sendRequest'])){
    if( $_POST['sendRequest']=="scriviDatiUtente" ) {
    include "config.php";

    //I transfer my data in some variables from $_POST (which is empty -__- )
    $nome = $_POST['unome'];
    $cognome = $_POST['ucognome'];
    $codice = $_POST['ucodice'];
    $punteggio = $_POST['upunteggio'];

    //I insert data in Mysql database
    $querya = "INSERT into studente(id, nome, cognome) values('$codice', '$nome', '$cognome')";
    $inserimentoa = mysql_query($querya, $database);
    $queryb = "INSERT into esecuzione(punteggio, id_studente) values('$punteggio', '$codice')";
    $inserimentob = mysql_query($queryb, $database);
    mysql_close($database);
    }
    }
?>
```

This is `config.php`

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $database="vhfdb";

    //connessione a mysql
    $database = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    //seleziono in mysql il database vhfdb
    mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: I've already view others discussions about this argument but i didn't find the solutions.

Comment: Check the http servers access log file. Maybe the arguments are just sent as GET parameters.

Comment: Still waiting for the code after 15 minutes, I am out.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the request as POST ?  varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; and not as GET ?

Comment: Hi arkascha, sorry I'm late. What do you mean "Check the http servers access log file"? Where I can check it?

Comment: Hi Adrian Pirvulescu! Yes, I'm sure I've used the POST method.

Comment: arkascha, I've found the server access log file. And it says this:
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2014:16:32:13 +0100] "GET /MioQuizDB/MioQuizDB.swf HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2014:16:32:29 +0100] "POST /MioQuizDB/inserimentoDati.php HTTP/1.1" 200 62
__________________
The 1st row it's when I execute the swf file, and the 2nd row it's when I try to call the php page.

Comment: Guys guys, I've done it!!! It WORKS!! ^_^ The problem was this: into config.php file, on line number 10, "mysql_select_db($database)" should be "mysql_select_db('vhfdb')", not using $database variable! I've figured it out by checking the "server error log file"! Thank you so much arkascha!! :D Thanks to all of you guys!!

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
  // Assign a variable name for our URLVariables object
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    // Build the varSend variable
    // Be sure you place the proper location reference to your PHP config file here
    var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.yourwebsite.com/config_flash.php");
    varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    varSend.data = variables;
    // Build the varLoader variable
    var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

    variables.uname = "myvalue whatever its...";
    variables.sendRequest = "parse"; 
    // Send the data to the php file
    varLoader.load(varSend);

    // When the data comes back from PHP we display it here 
    function completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {

    var value1= event.target.data.var1;
    var value2 = event.target.data.var2;

     trace(value1);
     trace(value2 );

    }
```

Comment: Hi sajan kumar, this is exactly the opensource that I tried to execute initially, but neither this works properly.
My files are situated in the folder named "wamp/www/".

Comment: mmm..weird, remove the content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".i am not sure this will work.. just try.. i checked your code it was completely correct.

Comment: sajan kumar, that line is correct. Now it WORKS!! :D The problem was this: into config.php file, on line number 10, "mysql_select_db($database)" should be "mysql_select_db('vhfdb')", not using $database variable! I've figured it out by checking the "server error log file"!

Comment: that's is too weird..  you stored the database name in to a variable and passing it into mysql_select_db.. it should work anyways..am happy that worked for you :) (Y)